# How to solve complexity problems

Tags: asymptotics

I have a problem in algorithm subject.. I have to decide whether 127n^2+n^3−4745n^2 is Ω(n^2) or not. How can I do this? Thanks very much!

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? Do you understand the question? We could solve the exercise for you (in fact, somebody already has) but that probably wouldn't help you *understand*.

Answer (score 1):

$127n^2+n^3−4745n^2$ is equal to $n^3−4618n^2$

There are constants $n_0$ and $c$ such that $n^3−4618n^2 \geq \frac{1}{c}n^2$ for all $n \geq n_0$, so $127n^2+n^3−4745n^2$ is   $Ω(n^2)$.